# Comando - Cordova run android

Tags: android, apache-cordova, app-hibrido

Estou com problema na execução do comando "$cordova run android", veja na linha abaixo após executar o comando;

```
$cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/dev3/Android/Sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

A Variável de ambiente esta setada corretamente em /etc/environment.

```
$java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3~14.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

O que pode ter ocorrido?

O questionamento do colega me levou a conferir se minha variável de ambiente estava setada corretamente, ao verificar estava correto mas porém no entanto o comando

```
$javac -version --> estava apontando curiosamente para o jdk7;
```

Que me levou a conferir e setar através do comando update-alternatives meu compilador $javac

```
$sudo update-alternatives --config javac
Existem 2 escolhas para a alternativa javac (disponibiliza /usr/bin/javac).

  Selecção   Caminho                                      Prioridade Estado
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1071      modo automático
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1071      modo manual
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1069      modo manual
```

Comment: A variável `JAVA_HOME` deveria mesmo apontar pra dentro da pasta JVM? Isso não parece fazer sentido pra mim.

Comment: jbueno todas as versões do java  usualmente fica dentro /usr/lib/jvm/"versaodojava"

Comment: mas  o seu questionamento me ajudou a resolver o problema, 

o comando javac -version tava apontando para o jdk7

então setei para o jdk 8

com o comando  update-alternatives  --config javac 

e setei para o jdk8